# Injection of dependecy failed in multiple maven modules

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, spring-boot

Hi freinds i am developing multiple maven modules based project and i have develop a demo project which is working fine. the structure of project is like this

```
parent
    child1 
       src
       pom.xml
    child2
       src
       pom.xml
pom.xml
```

my parent pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>ChildModule1</module>
        <module>ChildModule2</module>
    </modules>


    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.aquevix.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my child1 pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.aquevix.parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ChildProject1</artifactId>

</project>
```

child2 pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.aquevix.parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ChildProject2</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aquevix.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChildProject1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.aquevix.rest.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In Child1 maven module i have added a User controller and in which i have added `UserService` object but it is getting failed when i run my project

I run my project using this command

```
mvn -X exec:java -pl ChildModule2 -Dexec.mainClass="com.aquevix.rest.App"
```

It gives me this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project ChildProject2: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.aquevix.service.UserService com.aquevix.rest.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aquevix.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()} -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project ChildProject2: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
```

Comment: Post your `App` class. And why aren't you using the `springBoot:run` to run your app?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution . I override the component scan @ComponentScan("com.aquevix") by default it search all the classes into "com.aquevix.rest" only